# DP array 0th element is initialized as 1 instead of 0

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I encountered the LeetCode [climbStairs problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/):

> You are climbing a staircase. It takes `n` steps to reach the top.
>
> Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?
>
> #### Example:
>
> - **Input:** `n = 3`
> - **Output:** `3`
> - **Explanation:** There are three ways to climb to the top.
>
>   1. 1 step + 1 step + 1 step
>   2. 1 step + 2 steps
>   3. 2 steps + 1 step
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `1 <= n <= 45`

I'm wondering about the below solution (taken from https://emre.me/coding-patterns/staircase/):

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = [0 for x in range(n+1)]
        dp[0] = 1
        dp[1] = 1

        
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2]
        
        return dp[n]
```

I assume each value of the `dp` list denotes the number of ways one can take to reach that step.

In that case, why do we initialize the value at `dp[0]` to 1 instead of 0? Anyone can explain its logic?

It works fine in a recursive/array implementation if I use `dp[0]=0` but with dynamic programming it only works with `dp[0]=1`.

Comment: What's the correct value for `dp[2]`?

Comment: @slothrop It's 2 (sum of previous two steps)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HariPrasad right, so if `dp[2]` is calculated as `dp[1] + dp[0]` (as per the formula in your code), then `dp[2]==2` and `dp[1]==1` implies that `dp[0]==1`. Notice that in the code in the webpage you linked to, `dp[2]` is **not** calculated using `dp[1] + dp[0]` - it's effectively hardcoded to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is that there is always at least one way to reach the top of the stairs. If the staircase has no stairs (n = 0), then there is still one way to climb the stairs, i.e. by taking no steps. Note that it is not the *number of steps* for reaching the top that counts (which is zero here), but the number of *ways* (which is still one).

Although the code challenge states that n will be at least 1, we could extend this function to also work when n is 0. In that case we don't need `dp[1]` (which would be an invalid index), so we need to touch the code a little bit to make that work. For instance, we could naively foresee one more element in the `dp` list:

```
        dp = [0 for x in range(n+2)]
```

Now you can call the function with `n` equal to 0 and it will return 1, which is correct, and is the value at `dp[0]`. Again, the *number of ways* to climb a staircase that has no stairs is one (not zero).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense but in https://emre.me/coding-patterns/staircase/ if you check the brute force solution it returns 0 for n==0. May be it's wrong?

Comment: So what do you think yourself? When you arrive at a staircase with 0 stairs you are already at its top level. How many ways are there to get there? I would say just 1 -- that one way consists of 0 steps. If you say there 0 ways, you're saying it is impossible to reach the "top", yet there you are. So in my opinion 0 is wrong. But again, the code challenge says n is at least one, so this case isn't considered.

Comment: BTW, the code you refer to says in a code comment *"# we don't take any steps, so there is only 1 way"*, but the code below it is not consistent with that comment, so yes, I would say that is a typo of the author. They had the right intention expressed in their code-comment, but they didn't translate that comment into code correctly.

Comment: @HariPrasad It's "wrong", but they get away with it because they never actually use that value. The recursion calls `self.climbStairs(n - 1)` and `self.climbStairs(n - 2)` but it is only applied when `n` is 3 or above. So `self.climbStairs(0)` is never called in a recursion. If they corrected the solution for `n==0`, then they could remove their hardcoded solution for `n==2`.